# How to use ansible to switch vlans on a Juniper Switch

Tags: ansible, junos-automation

I am using a variant of the example provided [junipernetworks.junos.junos_l2_interfaces – L2 interfaces resource module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/junipernetworks/junos/junos_l2_interfaces_module.html#ansible-collections-junipernetworks-junos-junos-l2-interfaces-module)

My playbook

```
- name: Switch VLAN
  hosts: all
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: Replace VLAN
      junipernetworks.junos.junos_l2_interfaces:
        config:
          - name: xe-0/0/16
            access:
              vlan: 100
        state: replaced
```

Output from Ansible:

```
[WARNING]: ['connection local support for this module is deprecated and will be removed in version 2.14, use connection ansible.netcommon.netconf']
fatal: [10.70.44.76]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (junipernetworks.junos.junos_l2_interfaces) module: provider Supported parameters include: config, running_config, state"}
```

So I updated the connection type to use netconf as recommend by the warning (and enabled netconf on the switch)

Updated Playbook:

```
- name: Switch VLAN
  hosts: all
  connection: ansible.netcommon.netconf
  tasks:
    - name: Replace VLAN
      junipernetworks.junos.junos_l2_interfaces:
        config:
          - name: xe-0/0/16
            access:
              vlan: 100
        state: replaced
```

Results in a Failed play but cryptic message

```
fatal: [10.70.44.76]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "b'None'"}
```

So next I tried their persistent connection:

```
- name: Switch VLAN
  hosts: all
  connection: juniper.device.pyez
  tasks:
    - name: Replace VLAN
      junipernetworks.junos.junos_l2_interfaces:
        config:
          - name: xe-0/0/16
            access:
              vlan: 100
        state: replaced
```

Results in a 3rd error!

```
fatal: [10.70.44.76]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Method not found"}
```

Anything else I am missing or can try?

Comment: That is almost certainly an issue with that collection, so I'd recommend [filing an issue with them](https://github.com/ansible-collections/junipernetworks.junos/issues). Or, since ansible is just python, you can look at the module's source code and troubleshoot things locally, too

Answer (score 0):

I had solve the problem. Maybe you forget add variables "ansible_network_os: junipernetworks.junos.junos" when you use "connection: ansible.netcommon.netconf".